# Meteor : Create user specific collections when user registers at both client and server ends

Tags: mongodb, meteor

In my meteor app, I want to create a separate set of collections for every user when they register. The names of the collections will depend on the user id. For example, if a user with id `xyz` logs in, then I'd like to create some collections like `xyz_collection1` , `xyz_collection2` and so on..These collections are created when the user first registers. And on creation, these should be published by the server and subscribed to by the client. An example scenario: Each user has a set of bills scheduled for next month. When the user logs in, I want to show only *his* bills that are scheduled for next month. There can be two approaches:

1. I can have one collection named "NextMonthBills" which contains the bills for all the users that are due for next month. Then when a particular user logs in, I fetch from this collection only those bills belonging to him. (this is easier to implement)
2. I can have separate "NextMonthBills" collections for each user; of the form "user1_NextMonthBills", "user2_NextMonthBills" and so on. Then when a user logs in, I fetch all the data from the collection belonging to that user id.

**Question 1:**
I chose the 2nd one. Does it make sense data-security-wise?

**Question 2**
On the client side, I can get the user id easily. How do I send this to the server , so it can publish the relevant collections?  How do I get the server `publish` to run only when the user registers. ? Is this possible?

Comment: The answer is you never want dynamically created questions.

Comment: @DavidWeldon Realized from reading your article, that dynamic collections may be a bad idea..Thanks